# Не верный переход по ссылке vk bot

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, бот

Пишу бота для вк, делаю получение токена пользователя по ссылке.
Есть ссылка на получение кода для получения токена:
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=8169690&scope=1073737727&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/callback&display=page&response_type=code&revoke=1
Она завязана на кнопку в чатботе с типом Open Link
С браузера все ок - открывается окно разрешения доступа приложения
Но с мобильной открывается заблокированная группа https://vk.com/oauth
Код кнопки:

```
keyboard_1.add_callback_button(label='Откртыть Url', color=VkKeyboardColor.POSITIVE, payload={"type": "open_link", "link": "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=XXX&scope=XXX&redirect_uri=XXX/callback&display=mobile&response_type=code&revoke=1"})
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Даже отсюда, с мобильной версии открывается эта группа...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать сократить ссылку с помощью [vk.cc](https://vk.com/cc), мне это помогло.